# Create a LinkedResource of an Image obtained from a URL on the server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a form that allows a user to upload an image and then email it. The image is stored in the database as `varbinary`. I have a page called `image.aspx`. That page looks for a query string such as `image.aspx?id=10022` and then searches the database and finds the image with id `10022`.

Once I have the `bytes` I do this on `image.aspx`

```
Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
Response.Flush();
Response.End();
```

This produces a page with just the image that is stored in the database. Similar if you went to a url that was `www.website.come/image.jpg`, except it looks like `website.com/image.aspx?id=10022`

Then on the original upload form I display the image in an `Image Control` that is given an image url on the upload.

```
protected void upBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     byte[] image = FileUp.FileBytes;
     String name = FileUp.FileName;
     int id = db.UploadImage(name, image);
     productImg.ImageUrl = "~/image.aspx?id=" + id.ToString();
}
```

The image is immediately displayed in the image control. My next step is where I am having issues. I am trying to create a `LinkedResource` of this image by writing it to a `stream`, however I get a `System.ArgumentException: Illegal characters in path.` error no matter what I try.

This is how I am attempting to create the `LinkedResource`.

```
LinkedResource res = new LinkedResource(GetStreamFromUrl(path), MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg));
private Stream GetStreamFromUrl(string url)
{
     byte[] imageData = null;
     using (var wc = new System.Net.WebClient())
         imageData = wc.DownloadData(Server.MapPath(url));//the error happens right here

     return new MemoryStream(imageData);
}
```

The path in this case is going to be obtained from the `productImg.ImageUrl` and it is equal to `~/image.aspx?id=10022`. Can someone help explain

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the image is in the database, why get it from an url. That is just an extra step. Use the byte array directly. That is how I would do it.

```
byte[] image = yourImageByteArray;
Stream stream = new MemoryStream(image);
LinkedResource res = new LinkedResource(stream, MediaTypeNames.Image.Jpeg);
```

Comment: It seemed easier to do it that way since I was already displaying the image, but ill try this way